# Failed to initialise COM because the Virtual Box global directory is not accessible in MAC OSX

Tags: macos, virtualbox, osx-elcapitan

While I tried to install Virtual box on my OSX using GUI, it was not going through the verification step.

So, I tried installing using command line, which installed the VirtualBox

`drwxr-xr-x   3 root   admin    102 Aug  9 08:46 VirtualBox.app`

But I am unable to open it due to the below error

> Failed to initialise COM because the Virtual Box global directory is not accessible in MAC OSX

I am new to OSX and it has just been 1 day, please consider if this seems to be silly question.

Comment: Just to clarify: you've downloaded the official installer from virtualbox.org and it failed to install?

Comment: yes, But tired installing using command line and it got installed and am not able to open it